# Fedora 32 / dir has 73.4 gb but my disk it 1TB my home has ~700 gb

Tags: fedora

my fedora system is attached to a 1TB disk but the / only has 73.4 gb and my home directory has ~700 gb why?
df -h

```
    Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                 5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                    5.8G  149M  5.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                    5.8G  2.3M  5.8G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root   69G   66G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                    5.8G   24K  5.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/loop5                               128K  128K     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29
/dev/loop4                                63M   63M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/sda1                                976M  315M  595M  35% /boot
/dev/loop3                               162M  162M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop2                                98M   98M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/9289
/dev/loop0                                58M   58M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/discord/109
/dev/loop1                                55M   55M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1754
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home  841G  109G  689G  14% /home
tmpfs                                    1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                    1.2G  196K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                                1.7T  125G  1.5T   8% /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Large
/dev/sdb2                                221G   18G  203G   9% /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Small
```

mount

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=6036936k,nr_inodes=1509234,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=17257)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hello-world_29.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_128.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9289.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/9289 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_109.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/discord/109 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1754.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1754 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/42 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1212744k,mode=700,uid=42,gid=42)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1212744k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Large type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Small type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
[juliefilm@localhost /]$ df -h
df: /run/user/1000/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                 5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                    5.8G  149M  5.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                    5.8G  2.3M  5.8G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root   69G   66G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                    5.8G   24K  5.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/loop5                               128K  128K     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29
/dev/loop4                                63M   63M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/sda1                                976M  315M  595M  35% /boot
/dev/loop3                               162M  162M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop2                                98M   98M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/9289
/dev/loop0                                58M   58M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/discord/109
/dev/loop1                                55M   55M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1754
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home  841G  109G  689G  14% /home
tmpfs                                    1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                    1.2G  196K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                                1.7T  125G  1.5T   8% /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Large
/dev/sdb2                                221G   18G  203G   9% /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Small
[juliefilm@localhost /]$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=6036936k,nr_inodes=1509234,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=17257)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hello-world_29.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/hello-world/29 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_128.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9289.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/9289 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_109.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/discord/109 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1754.snap on /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1754 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/42 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1212744k,mode=700,uid=42,gid=42)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1212744k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Large type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /run/media/juliefilm/Dev_Small type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

gparted [image: my 1TB disk in gparted]

**solved: /usr wasnt writable odd but ok WORNG (still need answers)**

Comment: The screenshot doesn't help much, it doesn't show what's inside the LVM volume. But what is your question anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/home` has 689 GiB of free space, but 841 GiB total. Besides you have a 69 GiB root partition `/` and 976 MiB `/boot`. That's 911 GiB total, or 978 GB - almost 1 TB. You may have some unallocated space or metadata overhead, we'd need a GParted screenshot to check that.

Comment: https://flic.kr/p/2jdWwyK

Comment: @juls07 Again, please add relevant information to your question by editing it. Otherwise it's prone to link rot. I've already explained it in my previous comment.

Comment: its an image i cant add an image to my post